# Code coverage not getting increased, getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My code coverage is not getting increased. I'm getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error. Kindly help me in fixing errors!

Constructor:

```apex
public SampleDeliveryController() {

    this.CallReportId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cr');
    IsFormEnable = false;
    ShowBlock = true;
    ShowItemInStock = '';
    lotExpiredays = null;
    selectedCustomerName = '';
    sampleDelivery = new Sample_Delivery__c();
    mapStock = new Map<Id,String>();
    mapType = new Map<Id,String>();
    mapStockRem = new Map<Id,decimal>();
    loggedInUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    User loggedUser = GetLoggedInUser(loggedInUserId);
    currencyCode = loggedUser.DefaultCurrencyIsoCode;
    System.debug('Logged User ----->'+loggedUser);
    customerIds = new list<string>();
    conList = new list<contact>();
    TF__c targetFrequency = GetMarketingCycle(loggedUser);
    
    //for group name
    mapModule = new Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>>();
    moduleCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
    moduleList = new List<String>(); 

    if(targetFrequency<>null){
        Target_KPI__c limitPerCallFields = GetLimitPerCall(loggedUser,targetFrequency);
        if(limitPerCallFields.Limit_Per_Call__c == null){
            limitPerCallFields.Limit_Per_Call__c = 0; 
        }
        if(limitPerCallFields.Limit_Max_Per_Call__c == null){
            limitPerCallFields.Limit_Max_Per_Call__c = 0; 
        }
        this.limitpercalls = limitPerCallFields;
    }

    List<Call_Report__c>  liCallReport = [select id, Contact1__c,Is_Group_Call__c ,Group_Call_Customers_Id__c , Group_Call_Customers__c,Contact1__r.Name,Contact1__r.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c,createddate from Call_Report__c  where id =:CallReportId ];
    if (liCallReport.size() >0) {
        this.customerName = liCallReport[0].Contact1__r.Name;
        this.CustomerId = liCallReport[0].Contact1__c ;
        this.callCreatedDate = liCallReport[0].createddate ;
        this.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus = liCallReport[0].Contact1__r.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c;

        // Added by fawad --->  checking if  Group_Call_Customers__c  is true or not
        // check custom setting for Group Call
        country = loggedUser.Custom_Object_Country__c;
        SampleManagementSettings__c sampleManag  =SampleManagementSettings__c.getvalues(country);
        system.debug('>>>' +sampleManag.Samples_On_GroupCall__c);
        isControlled =  sampleManag.IsSampleControlled__c;
        lotExpiredays = sampleManag.Lot_Expiration_Days__c;
        system.debug('exp days' + sampleManag.Lot_Expiration_Days__c);
        if(currencyCode == 'BRL'){
          this.showExpireProduct =true;
        }else{
            this.showExpireProduct =false;
        }
    
        if(sampleManag.Samples_On_GroupCall__c == true && liCallReport[0].Group_Call_Customers__c != null && liCallReport[0].Is_Group_Call__c ==true ) {
            this.isGroupCustomer  = true;
            this.showPickList     = true;
            this.showCustomerName = false;
            
            string NameList   = liCallReport[0].Group_Call_Customers__c;
            customerNameList  =  NameList.split(';');
            customerNameList.add(this.customerName);
        
            //this.showExpireProduct = true;
            system.debug('customerNameList' + customerNameList);
            system.debug('customerNameList[0]' + customerNameList[0]);
            if(customerNameList.size()>0){
                conList= [select id, name,SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c from contact where  name =:customerNameList[0]];
                if(conList[0].SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c != 'Agreed'){
                    this.saveBtnDisable = true;
                }else{
                    this.saveBtnDisable = false;
                } 
            }
        }else{
            if(liCallReport[0].Contact1__r.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c != 'Agreed'){
                this.saveBtnDisable = true;
            }else{
                this.saveBtnDisable = false;
            }
            this.showPickList = false;
            this.showCustomerName = true;
            // this.showExpireProduct = false;
            this.isGroupCustomer = false;
            //this.saveBtnDisable =  false;
        }
    }

    populateSampleList();
    expireStockDescriptionList();
    getData();
}
```

Test method

```apex
@istest class
public static @istest void UnitTest2(){

    User loggedInUser = [SELECT id , Name, Business_Unit__c,DefaultCurrencyIsoCode, Custom_Object_Country__c FROM User WHERE id =:UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1]; 

    string aRecordTypeID;
    user usrlist = [SELECT id , Name, Custom_Object_Country__c, Business_Unit__c,DefaultCurrencyIsoCode FROM User WHERE id =:loggedInUser.Id];
        
    system.debug('Debugging usrlist loggedInUser>>>>'+ usrlist);
    //string country = [SELECT id , Name,Custom_Object_Country__c, DefaultCurrencyIsoCode FROM User WHERE id =:loggedInUser.Id].Custom_Object_Country__c;
    //ClmSuiteCountrySettings__c testcs = new ClmSuiteCountrySettings__c(Name = UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency(), ClmSuiteCountrySettings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency()).IsSampleMoreThanLimitEnabled__c=true);  

    //insert testcs;
    Account acc = DataFactoryUtilTest.createAccount(aRecordTypeID);
    
    Contact con = DataFactoryUtilTest.createContact(acc.Id); 
    //con.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c='Agreed';
    
    insert con;
    List<Contact> conList=[SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact WHERE id=: con.Id limit 10];
   
    Marketing_Cycle__c planningcycle= DataFactoryUtilTest.createPlanningCycle();
    insert planningcycle;
    Target__c target = DataFactoryUtilTest.createTarget();
    //target.CurrencyIsoCode='MXN';
    target.MedRep__c=loggedInUser.Id;

    insert target;
    
    TF__c targetclientlist = DataFactoryUtilTest.createTargetClientList(target.Id, con.Id);
    targetclientlist.Marketing_Cycle__c = planningcycle.Id;
    targetclientlist.CurrencyIsoCode = UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
    targetclientlist.Target__c = target.Id;
    targetclientlist.MedRep__c = loggedInUser.Id;
    insert targetclientlist;

    //List<SampleManagementSettings__c> SampleManagementSettingscList=[SELECT Id, Name,Lot_Expiration_Days__c, IsSampleControlled__c,Samples_On_GroupCall__c FROM SampleManagementSettings__c];
    
    SampleManagementSettings__c samplemanage=new SampleManagementSettings__c();
    samplemanage.DayZero2__c=date.today();
    samplemanage.Name='test';
    upsert samplemanage;
    string country=[SELECT id , Name, Custom_Object_Country__c FROM User WHERE id =:UserInfo.getUserId()].Custom_Object_Country__c;
    Call_Report__c callrep= new Call_Report__c();//DataFactoryUtilTest.createCallReportData(con.Id, aProductID, target.Id, 4);
    callrep.Contact1__c=con.Id;
    callrep.User__c=loggedInUser.Id;
    callrep.Type__c='1:1';
    callrep.CreatedById=loggedInUser.Id;
    callrep.Signature_taken__c=datetime.now();
    callrep.CurrencyIsoCode=loggedInUser.DefaultCurrencyIsoCode;
    callrep.Test_Text__c='test'; 
    callrep.Is_Group_Call__c=false;

    insert callrep;
    List<Call_Report__c>  liCallReport = [SELECT id, Contact1__c,Is_Group_Call__c ,Group_Call_Customers_Id__c , Group_Call_Customers__c,Contact1__r.Name,Contact1__r.SampleDeliveryAgreementStatus__c,createddate FROM Call_Report__c  WHERE id=:callrep.Id limit 1 ];

    test.startTest();          
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('cr', callrep.Id);
    SampleDeliveryController sdc = new SampleDeliveryController();
    test.stopTest();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title mentions an error, can you add verbatim to the question?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to describe the specific line that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
country = loggedUser.Custom_Object_Country__c;
SampleManagementSettings__c sampleManag  =SampleManagementSettings__c.getvalues(country);
```

Here, you are using **Custom_Object_Country__c** value of the logged in user to get the custom setting record. The country value that you are using in test class to create the custom setting is 'test'.

```
samplemanage.Name='test';
upsert samplemanage;
```

The logged in user is not having '*test*' as the **Custom_Object_Country__c** field value. You will not get the error if you use the same Custom_Object_Country__c as the logged in user to create the custom setting in test class.

However, it is recommended not to use logged in user in test class.
Please create a test user in the test class with a Custom_Object_Country__c field value. Use System.runAs() to run on user context. Follow below link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm